# specify the page to be directed after signing in with google+

Tags: google-plus, google-api-php-client

what is the code that specifies, for example, to direct user(after signing in) to 'login.php' on signincallback() method?

```
    function signinCallback(authResult)
{
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) 
        {---------------what to put here------------------} 

    else {console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are logged in (something like a *cookie*) then call:

```
document.location.assign("https://www.example.com/profile/profile_open_page.php");
```